# App freezes when CoroutineDispatcher is called inside a CoroutineDispatcher

Tags: java, android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a fun in MyActivity that looks like this

```
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
                mainFunction()
            }
```

and a mainFunction fun

```
private suspend fun mainFunction() = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {

                if (test1!!) {
                    some code                          
                } else {
                   some code 
                }     
    }
```

and test1 fun

```
 private suspend fun test1(start: Date): Boolean? {
        try {        
            if (status?.code == 200) {
              some code
           true
            } else if status?.code == 401) {
                reLoginUser()
               true
            }

        } catch (e: IOException) {
            false
        }
        return true
    }
```

reLoginUser fun

```
private suspend fun reLoginUser() {
       re login code
        if (loginResponse != null && statusCode == 200) {
           mainFunction()          
        } 
        } else {
           some code
        }
    }
```

I needed to introduce reLoginUser fun in this way. Since then, my app freezes when everything is executed. Job is done, but app freezes. I don't know why is that, I guess it has something with calling mainFunction() practically inside a mainFunction(). What is the right way to do this? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting caught in an infinite loop.

My guess is that your `status.code` is always 401 (for some reason, maybe internet connect or something) so your `test1` function calls `reLoginUser()` which tries to log in again and gets the same error (401) which causes this loop to start again.

So, comment out this line : `reLoginUser()`. if your code doesn't freeze, it means you have to rewrite your `reLoginUser()` function and avoid getting caught in a loop.